# Timing issue in windows rather than linux

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following function from a colleague who was previously working for the company and the comments are self explanatory, the problem is I'm right now using windows, and there issues with the synchornization with the device.

Would someone address or know a solution in windows for sync with a device ?

```
def sync_time(self):
        """Sync time on SmartScan."""
        # On a SmartScan time can be set only by the precision of seconds
        # So we need to wait for the next full second until we can send
        # the packet on it's way to the scanner.
        # It's not perfect, but the error should be more or less constant.
        message = Maint()
        message.state = message.OP_NO_CHANGE

        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        epoch = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)

        # int and datetime objects
        seconds = int((now - epoch).total_seconds()) + 1  # + sync second
        utctime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)

        # wait until next full second
        # works only on Linux with good accuracy
        # Windows needs another approach
        time.sleep((utctime - datetime.datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds())

        command = MaintRfc()
        command.command = command.SET_CLOCK
        command.data = (seconds, )
        message.add_message(command)

        self._handler.sendto(message)
        LOG.debug("Time set to: %d = %s", seconds, utctime)
```

Comment: You need to tell us *what* the issues are.

Comment: What do you expect this code to do, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: Timing issues between linux and windows, I'm trying to sleep for one second, I'm also trying to sleep for exactly one second

Comment: The goal was to sleep until the next whole second.

Comment: my issue is I want to wait until one second is passed for both platforms windows and linux